# PolicyMon - How to determine the policies my application uses?

Tags: policy

We (company) have written a pretty large software application over the last couple of years and we have just started running it under non-admin (restricted) accounts - as we are doing this we are realizing that there are certain OS (Windows XP) level policies that we needed. I have been tasked with identifying these policies up-front.

I have been looking and have been unable to find any kind of "policy monitoring" software (like regmon and filemon) so I am looking to create my own, something that I can run in the background while I perform operations on my application. The goal is to find out what "policies" I "hit" and identify them as ones I need to set (this part is easy - setting the policies programmatically).

Does anyone know if there is some API or something I can use to hook into the policy part of WindowsXP to setup some kind of monitor (or other suggestions?